# How to remove a line in a file BASH?

Tags: bash, compare

My question more specifically is:

I want that my code compare last two lines in a file and if they have the same content the programm delete the last line.

Ty.

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understood that you are comparing only last two line of a file and deleting it if it is same. Please try the below command

```
#!/bin/bash
set -- `tail -n 2 file | uniq -c`
case $1 in
  2) sed -i '$d' file ;;
  *) echo "something else";;
esac
```